# Can a view component call its own methods via ajax after rendering within the parent page?

Tags: kendo-ui, razor-pages

Maybe I am missing the point, but if you have a ViewComponent, the examples ive seen so far, all do their work within their 'InvokeAsync method, where they are passed a model and return a view.

If the view contains a databound control and you need to bind to data via Ajax, where can those methods be, within the ViewComponent or the parent page?

Ok, so take this example
https://github.com/pkellner/progress-telerik-blog-viewcomponent/tree/master/WebApp/Pages/Components/RatingControl

Can the viewcomponent be used for helper methods that are called from its own view, eg with Ajax loading. Same question goes for other controls as well, eg a DataGrid within a viewcomponent, where would the variosu crud helper methods go?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it finally dawned on me that NO you can not do what was suggesting.  Per the docs, a ViewComponent (as least as of 3.0) do not respond directly as an http endpoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Solution - make an http endpoint, eg.  a web api, which could be called via jquery/ajax from the markup in the viewcomponent.